# Is type casting have performance impact in Spring webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I am writing spring webflux micro services. For which I am using WebClient to make http calls.
For code reusability I have written my WebClient such a way to handle generic request and response.

Due to this I need to cast my request and response each time webclient is called.

```
public <Request, Response> Mono<response> process(request request,
                                                      Class<response> responseType) {
        
        
             return webClient.post().uri(url)
                .headers(all -> all.setAll(header))
                .body(getPayload(request), buildRequestObject(request)).retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(responseType).doOnError((throwable) -> {
                    Mono.error(
                            handleError((Throwable) throwable));
                });

    }

//This method is called to convert Generic response to Target Response object.
protected <T> Mono<T> castResponse(Object response, Class<T> responseType) {
        if (Objects.nonNull(response)) {
            Mono responseMono = (Mono) response;
            return responseMono.cast(responseType);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

So this method will return a Generic response. I am doing a casting of response object to target object every time. Does this have any performance overhead?

Is it bad practice to have this kind of generic webclient implementation.

Comment: What do you want to achieve, what the generic mono does not provide? And besides that- calling a remote resource via webclient is much more of an performance impact than any casting or whatsoever operation. So if you think you need a cast or even an reflection operation, it will not really add to the operations overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will have an impact in the JVM side.
WebFlux is just a Framework to manage the calls as an asynchronous mode instead of regular java synchronous calls. But in the bottom of the Framwework we always going to have a JVM that has to work in the same way as using this Framework or not.
So, a casting for the JVM means additional operation to check and convert the object and sometimes a trash bin action.

Do you have to do it in different way? It dependes on:

- This program needs to apply aggresive actions for improving the performance? -> In this case is clear that is wrong.
- The program don't have an especific requeriment on performance? -> You have to evaluate if the code that you have introduced there has a very positive impact in terms of clean code, readability, the amount of calls that you will have to the method, etc